# Build/make on git server or on client

Tags: android, git, native-code

I have cloned a git repo from a server and considering to make that local machien a git server for local git clients, I don't know if I should build/make the repo (application) on the server and then clone it to local git (client) or I should clone it first and then build/make it on my local machine !
This application has C code underlying Java, so I will deal with java, I think this underlying code which is in C is build/compiled when I am making/building it with make. So would it be not a good idea to build/make it on git server and then clone it, in this way not every client has to make it on every git client...

What do you think ?
BTW, is this underlying code in C is termed as native code ???

Regards